# Do not nest ternary expression - alternative

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this React component that can has 4 states: advisoryResults, results, noResults, newAccount.

I think it makes sense to do it with a ternary expression but this is not allowed, what can be a good alternative for that?

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isAdmin: false
  };

  render() {
    const { isAdmin } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div css={innerWrap}>
          {isAdmin ? (
            <Button
              onClick={this.handleAddNewContact }
            >
              Add new Contact
            </Button>
          ) : (
            ''
          )}
   {searchMode === searchModes.advisoryPanels ? (
            <>
              <SearchAdvisoryPanels />
              <div css={{ textAlign: 'center', margin: '60px auto' }}>
                <ManAtDesk />
              </div>
            </>
          ) : searchMode === searchModes.noResultsPanel ? (
            <SearchNoResultsPanel />
          ) : searchMode === searchModes.resultsPanel ? (
            accountInfo.map((info, index) => (
              <SearchResultPanel info={info} isAdmin={isAdmin} key={index} />
            ))
          ) : searchMode === searchModes.addContactPanel ? (
            <AddNewContactForm
              onCancelAccount={this.onCancelAccount}
              onSaveAccount={this.onSaveAccount}
            />
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to write an answer back when you asked this question with a switch statement.

Using a JSON containing every possible results could solve your problem without adding unnecessary code :

```
render() {
    const { isAdmin } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <div css={innerWrap}>
                {isAdmin && <Button onClick={this.handleAddNewContact}> Add new Contact</Button>}
                {
                    {
                        [searchModes.SearchAdvisoryPanels]: (
                            <>
                                <SearchAdvisoryPanels />
                                <div css={{ textAlign: 'center', margin: '60px auto' }}>
                                    <ManAtDesk />
                                </div>
                            </>
                        ),
                        [searchModes.noResultsPanel]: <SearchNoResultsPanel />,
                        [searchModes.resultsPanel]: accountInfo.map((info, index) => (<SearchResultPanel info={info} isAdmin={isAdmin} key={index} />)),
                        [searchModes.addContactPanel]: <AddNewContactForm  onCancelAccount={this.onCancelAccount} onSaveAccount={this.onSaveAccount} />
                    }[searchMode]
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

However this solution will mount all your components even though they are not displayed, using arrow functions instead could increase the performance by only mounting the desired component :

```
render() {
    const { isAdmin } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <div css={innerWrap}>
                {isAdmin && <Button onClick={this.handleAddNewContact}> Add new Contact</Button>}
                {
                    {
                        [searchModes.SearchAdvisoryPanels]: () => (
                            <>
                                <SearchAdvisoryPanels />
                                <div css={{ textAlign: 'center', margin: '60px auto' }}>
                                    <ManAtDesk />
                                </div>
                            </>
                        ),
                        [searchModes.noResultsPanel]: () => <SearchNoResultsPanel />,
                        [searchModes.resultsPanel]: () => accountInfo.map((info, index) => (<SearchResultPanel info={info} isAdmin={isAdmin} key={index} />)),
                        [searchModes.addContactPanel]: () => <AddNewContactForm  onCancelAccount={this.onCancelAccount} onSaveAccount={this.onSaveAccount} />
                    }[searchMode]()
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

EDIT

If the variable can have a value different from every given option, you can implement the following solutions.

Either send a function that does not do anything if the value is undefined :

```
}[searchMode] || (x => x)()
```

Or store the result outside of your return and call the function if it exists :

```
render() {
    const { isAdmin } = this.state;
    const searchRender = {
        [searchModes.SearchAdvisoryPanels]: () => (
            <>
                <SearchAdvisoryPanels />
                <div css={{ textAlign: 'center', margin: '60px auto' }}>
                    <ManAtDesk />
                </div>
            </>
        ),
        [searchModes.noResultsPanel]: () => <SearchNoResultsPanel />,
        [searchModes.resultsPanel]: () => accountInfo.map((info, index) => (<SearchResultPanel info={info} isAdmin={isAdmin} key={index} />)),
        [searchModes.addContactPanel]: () => <AddNewContactForm onCancelAccount={this.onCancelAccount} onSaveAccount={this.onSaveAccount} />
    }[searchMode]

    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <div css={innerWrap}>
                {isAdmin && <Button onClick={this.handleAddNewContact}> Add new Contact</Button>}
                {searchRender && searchRender()}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

EDIT : What is this dark magic ?

The first step creates your JSON with [computed properties](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-object-creation-356e504173a8), it allows you to assign an Objects keys from variables rather that hardcoded values :

```js
const searchModes = {
    SearchAdvisoryPanels: "a",
    noResultsPanel: "b",
    resultsPanel: "c",
    addContactPanel: "d"
}

const result = {
    [searchModes.SearchAdvisoryPanels]: 1,
    [searchModes.noResultsPanel]: 2 ,
    [searchModes.resultsPanel]: 3,
    [searchModes.addContactPanel]: 4
}

console.log(result)
```

We can now replace the values `1 2 3 4` with whatever we want. In this case, arrow functions. To get the result you want, just add braces at the end of the JSON :

```js
const searchModes = {
    SearchAdvisoryPanels: "a",
    noResultsPanel: "b",
    resultsPanel: "c",
    addContactPanel: "d"
}

const search = "c"

const result = {
    [searchModes.SearchAdvisoryPanels]: 1,
    [searchModes.noResultsPanel]: 2 ,
    [searchModes.resultsPanel]: 3,
    [searchModes.addContactPanel]: 4
}[search]

console.log(result)
```

If the values returned are converted to functions, you only have to add parenthesis at the end of your thing to call it :

```js
const searchModes = {
    SearchAdvisoryPanels: "a",
    noResultsPanel: "b",
    resultsPanel: "c",
    addContactPanel: "d"
}

const search = "c"

const result = {
    [searchModes.SearchAdvisoryPanels]: () => 1,
    [searchModes.noResultsPanel]: () => 2 ,
    [searchModes.resultsPanel]: () => 3,
    [searchModes.addContactPanel]: () => 4
}[search]()

console.log('Short : ' + result)

//Long syntax :

const options = {
    [searchModes.SearchAdvisoryPanels]: () => 1,
    [searchModes.noResultsPanel]: () => 2 ,
    [searchModes.resultsPanel]: () => 3,
    [searchModes.addContactPanel]: () => 4
}

const action = options[search]

const output = action()

console.log('Long : ' + output)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried that but I'm getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: ((intermediate value)(intermediate value) , _defineProperty(...) , _defineProperty(...) , _defineProperty(...) , _searchModes$SearchAd)[searchMode] is not a function`

Comment: Oh.. can `searchMode` have a value corresponding to none of the options given ? If so i'll need to check if the variable exists

Comment: Sorry, my fault, found the issue. Thank so much for the great answer, would you be able to give me a short explanation on how it works?

Comment: I updated my answer with 2 possible solution to the problem I mentioned above. Alright, glad it could help. Sure, I'll explain right after

Comment: More than perfect! Thank you!

Comment: This is not great. You are defining a "complex" object with arrow function every time your component renders (or re-renders). As yourself mentioned: dark magic. This pattern you just proposed is never-seen and I'd advocate against doing it.

Comment: Creating function has an incredibly low performance cost, rather than putting raw computed objects. A switch statement would do the exact same thing internally. The ternary function would be quicker for sure, by an insignificant amount, but would greatly impact code readability, as well as nested `if`

Comment: It simply is not. You will find a performance test between both methods here : https://jsperf.com/alternateswitch/5. My answer works 4x better on chrome, and this other one works 2x better on Firefox.

Comment: Kudos for the very thorough comparison @Treycos !

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest doing something like this:

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isAdmin: false
  };

  onCancelAccount = () => {};
  onSaveAcciont = () => {};

  renderSearchResults = (searchMode) => {
    const { info, isAdmin, index } = this.props;

    switch (searchMode) {
      case searchModes.advisoryPanels:
        return this.renderAdvisoryPanels();
      case searchModes.noResultsPanel:
        return <SearchNoResultsPanel />;
      case searchModes.resultsPanel:
        return <SearchResultPanel info={info} isAdmin={isAdmin} key={index} />;
      case searchModes.addContactPanel:
        return (
          <AddNewContactForm
            onCancelAccount={this.onCancelAccount}
            onSaveAccount={this.onSaveAccount}
          />
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  renderAdvisoryPanels = () => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <SearchAdvisoryPanels />
      <div css={{ textAlign: 'center', margin: '60px auto' }}>
        <ManAtDesk />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  render() {
    const { isAdmin } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div css={innerWrap}>
          {isAdmin && (
            <Button onClick={this.handleAddNewContact}>Add new Contact</Button>
          )}
          {this.renderSearchResults(searchMode)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Some of the handlers/props are not immediately visible from your example, so fix if I got something wrong.

Comment: It simply is not. You will find a performance test between both methods here : https://jsperf.com/alternateswitch/5. My answer works 4x better on chrome, and this one works 2x better on Firefox.

Comment: Whoa, I didn't think this will become such a big topic. I personally find both solutions to be good. The only difference maybe is the code writing style and readability, which are both very subjective topics. However, the difference between FF and Chrome seems mind-boggling tbh.

Comment: This is vastly more readable than accepted answer. I would say that the speed tradeoff (if true) is worth the readability and maintainability. You say 2x, 4x the speed which sounds a lot, bot we're probably talking about miliseconds either way, so I would prefer readability over minor speed increase any time.

Comment: I am refatoring my code, your answer is much more readable, not sure if it's fair enough to change now the accepted answer. I upvoted.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. No problem, there is something to be learned from both mine and accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should aways do on JS, move stuff to a fn. This approach keeps the render fn clear. Your getSearchMode has a clear reading, nothing complex is happening there. You are not setting an unnecessary object, not creating many functions inside your render function or doing any magic - just plain old JS.

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isAdmin: false,
  }

  getSearchMode = (searchMode) => {
    if (searchMode === searchModes.advisoryPanels) {
      return (
        <>
          <SearchAdvisoryPanels />
          <div css={{ textAlign: 'center', margin: '60px auto' }}>
            <ManAtDesk />
          </div>
        </>
      )
    }
    if (searchMode === searchModes.noResultsPanel) {
      return <SearchNoResultsPanel />
    }
    if (searchMode === searchModes.resultsPanel) {
      return accountInfo.map((info, index) => (
        <SearchResultPanel info={info} isAdmin={this.state.isAdmin} key={index} /> // you should not use index as key
      ))
    }
    if (searchMode === searchModes.addContactPanel) {
      return (
        <AddNewContactForm
          onCancelAccount={this.onCancelAccount}
          onSaveAccount={this.onSaveAccount}
        />
      )
    }
    return null
  }

  render() {
    const { isAdmin } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div css={innerWrap}>
          {isAdmin ? <Button onClick={this.handleAddNewContact}>Add new Contact</Button> : ''}
          {this.getSearchMode(searchMode)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```